CSV Data containing H3 data
I have point CSV data (has lat/lng) that includes H3 property named prop_json_array_of_uber_h3. It Contains an Array of Arrays which I presume make up some kind of tessellated coverage area using H3 hexagons. The Array itself appears to be of any length. The Arrays in the Array have 4 members (ie ["8b209058601bfff", 1, -91.0, -91]. The first is hex string that are decodable to lat/long using H3 libraries. I am unsure of the next 3 numbers - assume they tie into neighboring hexagons. Looking for explanation of what the last integers might be?
